# How to clear ckeditor form after submitting with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor, Jquery and plugin jquery form.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'comment-textarea' );
function CKupdate(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    var options = {
        success: function (html) {
            $('#comments').append(html);
        },
        clearForm: true 
    };

    $('#formcomments').submit(function() {
        CKupdate();
    });
    $('#formcomments').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

I am using **clearForm: true**, But after submiting a form, value of the textarea Ckeditor is not cleared. How to clear the textarea ckeditor?

Comment: so you want to clear fck after submit right

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I use function `setData` and all works fine:

```
function CKupdate(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData('');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'comment-textarea' );

    var options = {
        success: function (html) {
            $('#comments').append(html);
        },
        clearForm: true 
    };

    $('#formcomments').submit(function() {
        CKupdate();
    });
    $('#formcomments').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

Comment: If you solved it with this code, accept your own answer. Otherwise you're saying to the system that it's still unsolved. Do not edit to say SOLVED though

Answer (score 3):

Try something like `$("#comment-textarea").val("");`  ... it should go here.

```
$('#formcomments').submit(function() {
        CKupdate();
$("#comment-textarea").val("");
    });
```

`#comment-textarea` is the id of the textarea you want to clear and `.val(' ')` sets it's value to `' '` - notice the space between the ';

Answer (score 2):

Simply create instance and use `setHtml`

use this inside submit

```
var Editor1 = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('comment-textarea'');
Editor1.SetHTML();
```

for ckeditor

> setData

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData

Comment: That's only for the old FCKeditor, he asked about CKEditor that has a different API.

Answer (score 0):

I used this two method and worked for me

```js
$(window).load(function(e) {
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData('');
});

//OR

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'response.php',
    data: data,
    cache:false,
    success: function(e)
    {
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData('');
    }
});
```

Hope It helps

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.msg.setData('');
```

Comment: What is the benefit to using this approach, as opposed to `CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData('');` as suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443276/3025856) from nearly a decade ago?